# SQL two lookups into same fields on one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables that look like this:

```
create table users (
    user_id uuid,
    user_name varchar(32)
);

create table messages (
    message_id uuid,
    from_id uuid references users(user_id),
    to_id uuid references users(user_id),
    the_message varchar(140),
    primary key(message_id)
);
```

If I do the following:

```
select * from messages
```

I will be given UUIDs. I want to display the users.user_name for the given uuid. This gets me close:

```
select
    users.user_name as from_id,
    users.user_name as to_id
from messages
    join users on users.user_id = messages.from_id
;
```

The result displays the same user for both the "from" and the "to" field.

How do I display the user_name for the from_id, and also the user_name for the to_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the users table twice -- once for the from user and once for the to user:

```
select
    messages.*,
    f.user_name as from_id,
    t.user_name as to_id
from messages
    join users f on f.user_id = messages.from_id
    join users t on t.user_id = messages.to_id
;
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. The real block for me was the alias on the join. Without it, the database complains that you've already joined on the users table.

Comment: @Buddy -- np, glad I could help!